# Understanding Promise.all and Array.map()

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, asynchronous, promise

I am retrieving data from multiple API's and these data will be aggregated into a final array where I intend to map through and display in the UI (using React). So for better context, I have this kind of scenario.

First I retrieve the major data from the main API

```
const response = await getFirstData() // returns an array

const [secondResult, thirdResult, fourthResult] = await Promise.all([
 response.map(async (item) => await secondApiRequest()),
 response.map(async (item) => await thirdApiRequest()),
 response.map(async (item) => await fourthApiRequest())
])
```

As you can see from above, based on the `response` from the main API, I then map through the array returned to get data from other APIs `(secondApiRequest(), etc..)`. Now I was thinking that `secondResult`, `thirdResult`, `fourthResult` would resolve to an array of objects as it should be. But when I check the logs on chrome browser I see this instead.

```
0: Promise {<fulfilled>: Array(10)}
1: Promise {<fulfilled>: Array(10)}
2: Promise {<fulfilled>: Array(10)}
3: Promise {<fulfilled>: Array(10)}
4: Promise {<fulfilled>: Array(10)}
5: Promise {<fulfilled>: Array(5)}
6: Promise {<fulfilled>: Array(0)}
7: Promise {<fulfilled>: Array(0)}
8: Promise {<fulfilled>: Array(0)}
9: Promise {<fulfilled>: Array(0)}
```

I understand that these operations are run in parallel, but how do I get these operations to resolve and return the final arrays that should contain objects. Also, what would be the most efficient way to achieve this because the `finalArray` will contain more than 200 objects at the end and I have to display that on the UI. Thank you, any help is welcome.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to happen here @thatkingguy_? If `response` contains 10 items, do you want `secondApiRequest` to be called 10 times? If so, what should `secondResult` be, in relation to those 10 api calls?

Comment: @JamesMonger So `response` is an array of objects. I map through the `response` array and make other calls to `secondApiRequest` etc, now for each mapping, I am passing an `id` to the other API calls. E.g `response.map(async (item) => secondApiRequest(id))` the  `id` parameter is gotten from each object in the `response` array.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make all requests in parallel, you should return an array of promises to `Promise.all()`.

Map response for each api, and wait for it's array of promises with `Promise.all()`, then await all internal `Promise.all()` calls with an external one.

```
const response = await getFirstData() // returns an array

const [secondResult, thirdResult, fourthResult] = await Promise.all(
  [secondApiRequest, thirdApiRequest, fourthApiRequest]
    .map(api => Promise.all(response.map(api)))
)
```

Comment: By doing this you flatten the results, and you won't get the expected results in the `secondResult`, `thirdResult` and `fourthResult` variables

Comment: Thanks. Updated.

Comment: Also we don't really know if the items of `response` are actually the first parameters of every subsequent request

Comment: Doesn't matter in this case. If the function ignores the `item` it doesn't matter if you pass it. In your case you should do `() => secondApiRequest()`, if you wish to ignore the item.

Comment: Thanks. Did the same.

Answer (score 0):

This allows you to run the subsequent requests in parallel and retrieve their results in the corresponding variables:

```
const response = await getFirstData(); // returns an array

const [secondResult, thirdResult, fourthResult] = await Promise.all([
  Promise.all(response.map(item => secondApiRequest()),
  Promise.all(response.map(item => thirdApiRequest()),
  Promise.all(response.map(item => fourthApiRequest())
]);
```